# Javascript code is not working in html dropdown option element

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want to bind previous year in a html dropdown option in a html page.Below is my code

```
<option value="(new Date()).getFullYear() - 1;">(new Date()).getFullYear() - 1;</option>
```

Is this possible..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However, you can't just arbitrarily place JavaScript code in the middle of your HTML and expect it to be interpreted as JavaScript. That only applies for special attributes (`onclick`, for example), otherwise you need to use a `<script>` tag to indicate that it's JavaScript.

That said, I'd create just the HTML `<select>` element using the HTML, and then add the `<option>` element(s) using JavaScript, like so:

```
<select name="test" id="mySelect"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = (new Date()).getFullYear() - 1;
    option.innerHTML = (new Date()).getFullYear() - 1;

    select.appendChild(option);
</script>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9ABU/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind JavaScript to an element in the way you have described without using a framework such as AngularJs.

To do this with vanilla JavaScript you will need to include the JavaScript on the page to populate the option values, I would include it at the bottom of you page, something like this:

```
(function () {
    var previousYear = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
    document.getElementById('yearSelect').options[0].value = previousYear;
    document.getElementById('yearSelect').options[0].text = previousYear;
})();
```

Assuming your html is

```
<select id='yearSelect'>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rEat/1/)

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest isn't possible that way. You would have to create that option dynamically with JavaScript.

For a select box like this

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

the JavaScript would be

```
function loadOption() {

   var lastYear = new Date().getFullYear() -1; //Grab the year -1

   var newOpt = document.createElement("option"); //Create a new option element
   newOpt.value = lastYear;                       //Set it's value
   newOpt.innerHTML = lastYear;                   //Set it's text
   document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(newOpt); //Apend to your select box
}

//Then you can run loadOption() onload of the document or in a script tag underneath the element itself
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2GN5/1/)